# Regular expression to filter URLs that have more than one ampersand "&"

Tags: java, regex, nutch

I am using a web-crawler(called **Nutch**) which crawls the web when I feed in a bunch of urls into it. I set certain regular expression filters to control the crawler to specific domains and specific filters.

```
# skip URLs containing a back slash

-[\\]    

# skip URLS containing more than 6 levels

-^http://([a-zA-Z.-]+)/(?:[^/]+/){6,}.*$

# crawl only domain abc

+^http://www.abc.xx.yyy.zzz/pubs/([a-z]+)
```

**Issue**: Within the specific domain, my crawler is crawling all search form urls with all the pagination and query parameters which I don't want. Examples are:

```
http://www.abc.xx.yyy.zzz/pubs/biblio_results.asp?Library=ABC&SubjectScope=keyword&SubjectMode=contains&SubjectText=abc_archive&URLs=yes&Order=year&SortOrder=DESC&Abstracts=no
```

I am not sure how to set a regular expression to let my crawler ignore any such URL like the example above that has more than one "&" sign in its URL path.

On a side note, is it a good idea to ignore such URLs while building a search engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line in the Nutch config should be

```
-&.*&
```

This tells Nutch to skip anything with two or more `&` characters, and any number of characters between.

Whether it's a good idea to ignore such URLs depends on the purpose of your search engine, and the nature of the URLs within the domain that you're searching.  It's impossible to answer the last sentence of your question without understanding the problem domain.

Comment: thanks David for your post. I was asking that question in general to know if it is a practice followed by any standard public-facing search engine e.g. Google or Bing?

Comment: I don't believe either Google or Bing do such a thing - they certainly don't discard URLs with only two ampersands.  They might impose a different limit, say 32, but neither Google nor Microsoft is likely to release that information.

Comment: I explained it.  Two ampersands.  With any number of characters between.  The `-` is an instruction to Nutch and is not part of the regular expression.

Comment: if I have to change it to four or more?

Comment: I'd use `-&.*&.*&.*&` for simplicity and readability, although there's a slightly more efficient way of doing it, using negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 3):

Insert this negative lookahead after the head of string anchor `^`

```
(?![^&]*&){2}
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(?!                      # look ahead to see if there is not (2
                         # times):
  [^&]*                  #   any character except: '&' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  &                      #   '&'
){2}                     # end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

since you seem to be matching URLs which meet each case, then filtering by those, it is fairly simple to match URLs which DO contain 2 &s.

```
(&.*&)+
```

That will match anything containing a sequence with at least 2 ampersands

Comment: Either make it lazy `.*?` or use `[^&]*` to avoid unnecessary backtracking/matching.